# Unable to explain to model behavior in transfer learning

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have very small image dataset (747 images for training and 250 for testing where images are resized to 256 x 256).  The task is multi-label classification (between 2 infections which is possible to occur together but my training data does not have such a situation).

Since my dataset is very small, i decided to use transfer learning using VGG16 and InceptionV3.  When I train the VGG16, everything follows the theory, e.g. training loss and validation loss keep decreasing and not very much different value as shown in the Figure 1

[image: VGG16: batch_size=32, learning_rate=0.00001]

When i train the InceptionV3, it seems like model is over fit but I'm not sure about that because the training loss is about 0.6 while valdation loss is about 10 times of training loss as shown in Figure 2

[image: InceptionV3: batch_size=8, learning_rate=0.00001]

Both models were added 3 dense layers.  I attached the code for reference.  I could not find explanation why the very much bigger model (VGG) not overfit with this dataset but InceptionV3 does.  May I have suggestions what went wrong with InceptionV3?

```
def xvgg16(self, height, width, depth, num_class, hparams):
        """
        This function defines transfer learning for vgg16

        Parameters
        ----------
        height : Integer
            Image height (pixel)
        width : Integer
            Image width (pixel)
        depth : Integer
            Image channel
        num_class : Integer
            Number of class labels
        hparams: Dictionary
            Hyperparameters

        Returns
        -------
        model : Keras model object
            The transfer model

        """
        input_tensor = Input(shape=(height, width, depth))
        pretrain = VGG16(weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_tensor=input_tensor)

        conv1_1 = pretrain.layers[1]
        conv1_2 = pretrain.layers[2]
        pool1 = pretrain.layers[3]
        conv2_1 = pretrain.layers[4]
        conv2_2 = pretrain.layers[5]
        pool2 = pretrain.layers[6]
        conv3_1 = pretrain.layers[7]
        conv3_2 = pretrain.layers[8]
        conv3_3 = pretrain.layers[9]
        pool3 = pretrain.layers[10]
        conv4_1 = pretrain.layers[11]
        conv4_2 = pretrain.layers[12]
        conv4_3 = pretrain.layers[13]
        pool4 = pretrain.layers[14]
        conv5_1 = pretrain.layers[15]
        conv5_2 = pretrain.layers[16]
        conv5_3 = pretrain.layers[17]
        pool5 = pretrain.layers[18]

        x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(conv1_1.output)
        x = conv1_2(x)
        x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(x)
        x = pool1(x)
        x = conv2_1(x)
        x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(x)
        x = conv2_2(x)
        x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(x)
        x = pool2(x)
        x = conv3_1(x)
        x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(x)
        x = conv3_2(x)
        x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(x)
        x = conv3_3(x)
        x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(x)
        x = pool3(x)
        x = conv4_1(x)
        x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(x)
        x = conv4_2(x)
        x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(x)
        x = conv4_3(x)
        x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(x)
        x = pool4(x)
        x = conv5_1(x)
        x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(x)
        x = conv5_2(x)
        x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(x)
        x = conv5_3(x)
        x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(x)
        x = pool5(x)

        x = Flatten()(x)
        x = Dense(64, use_bias=False)(x)
        x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
        x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(x)
        x = Activation("relu")(x)

        x = Dense(64, use_bias=False)(x)
        x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
        x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(x)
        x = Activation("relu")(x)

        x = Dense(64, use_bias=False)(x)
        x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
        x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(x)
        x = Activation("relu")(x)

        x = Dense(num_class)(x)
        x = Activation("sigmoid")(x)

        model = Model(inputs=pretrain.layers[0].input, outputs=x)

        for layer in model.layers:
            if "conv" in layer.name:
                layer.trainable = False    

        model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=Adam(lr=hparams["learning_rate"]), metrics=["binary_accuracy"])

        return model

def inception3(self, height, width, depth, num_class, hparams):
        """
        This function defines transfer learning for densenet

        Parameters
        ----------
        height : Integer
            Image height (pixel)
        width : Integer
            Image width (pixel)
        depth : Integer
            Image channel
        num_class : Integer
            Number of class labels
        hparams: Dictionary
            Hyperparameters

        Returns
        -------
        model : Keras model object
            The transfer model
        """
        input_tensor = Input(shape=(height, width, depth))
        pretrain = InceptionV3(weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_tensor=input_tensor)

        x = pretrain.output
        x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)

        x = Dense(64, use_bias=False)(x)
        x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
        x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(x)
        x = Activation("relu")(x)

        x = Dense(64, use_bias=False)(x)
        x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
        x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(x)
        x = Activation("relu")(x)

        x = Dense(64, use_bias=False)(x)
        x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
        x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(x)
        x = Activation("relu")(x)

        x = Dense(num_class)(x)
        x = Activation("sigmoid")(x)

        model = Model(inputs=pretrain.input, outputs=x)

        for layer in pretrain.layers:
            layer.trainable = False

        model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=Adam(lr=hparams["learning_rate"]), metrics=["binary_accuracy"])

        return model
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know that both `VGG` and `Inception` models in `Keras` are pretrained using `imagenet`, but with different preprocessing function.

While `VGG` preprocesses images to have pixel values in the range `(0, 255)`, `Inception_v3` preprocesses them to have pixel values in the range `(-1, 1)`

Therefore, when you train VGG, you should first preprocess your input images as follows:

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
X_train = ... # read your training images
X_train = preprocess_input(X_train)
print(X_train.max(), X_train.min(), X_train.mean())
```

You will see that the maximum, minimum and average pixel values are in the range `(0, 255)`

For Inception_v3, you should follow this procedure:

```
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import preprocess_input
X_train = ... # read your training images
X_train = preprocess_input(X_train)
print(X_train.max(), X_train.min(), X_train.mean())
```

Here, the values will be between `-1` and `1`

In your current code, VGG works quite ok because your images have pixels in the range of 0 to 255 as expected by VGG model, but does not work for Inception V3 because it expects them in the range -1 and 1.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's great :)